# library problem ? how to solve this?

Tags: esp32

Arduino: 1.8.11 (Windows 10), Board: "ESP32 Dev Module, Disabled, Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS), 240MHz (WiFi/BT), QIO, 80MHz, 4MB (32Mb), 921600, None"

```
Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"
 Used: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.4\libraries\WiFi
 Not used: C:\Program
 In file included from C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\async-mqtt-client-master\src/AsyncMqttClient.h:4:0,
             from C:\Users\User\Desktop\sketch_jul13a\sketch_jul13a.ino:3:

C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\async-mqtt-client-master\src/AsyncMqttClient.hpp:9:22: fatal error: AsyncTCP.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: `Not used: C:\Program` - is that where you put your Arduino code, or is something going wrong with `C:\Program Files (x86)`?

Comment: sir what i have to do for this ? pls tell

Comment: i updated the ide but again it show same error

Comment: Then install the `Async TCP` library, or whag ever library gives you the file `AsyncTCP.h`. The compiler complains, that the file is missing, so most likely you didn't install all the needed libraries

Comment: do what it tells you to do at the end of the printout